# I get an error "An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll"

Tags: vb.net

This is my code:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Dim botgreetings
botgreetings = {"Hey!", "Hello there!"}

If greetings.IsMatch(TextBox1.Text) Then
    RichTextBox1.AppendText("Bot: " & botgreetings)
    RichTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine)
End If
```

And I get the message:

> > An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
>
> Additional information: Operator '&' is not defined for string "Bot: "
>   and type 'String()'.

I just want to make it go like:

If I wrote something in the textbox and I click the button "send", I want the "bot" to respond in several greetings instead of one. Tho it doesn't work! D:

Comment: hold your mouse over the "microsoft" tag

Comment: You are trying to append an array of strings to a string.  Kaboom.  Time to write code with Option Strict On for a while.